# Squid parent cache for text/html only

Tags: linux, squid

How do I configure the squid to only request text/html to the parent cache; right now I am using :
cache_peer 127.0.0.1 parent 8080 0 no-query no-digest

on the second hand I get a lot of direct request that do not use the parent proxy: some queries go like  FIRST_UP_PARENT and some like  DIRECT, how do I tell the squid to always use parent for text/html

BTW .. is a transparent proxy

I have tried :

```
cache_peer 127.0.0.1 parent 8080 0 no-query no-digest
acl elhtml req_mime_type -i ^text/html$
acl elhtml req_mime_type -i text/html
cache_peer_access 127.0.0.1 allow elhtml
cache_peer_access 127.0.0.1 deny all
```

and it does not works

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out you can't ealuate mime type responses before they go to a parent because the request is just being made; you don't have the mime type yet.

The best you can do is put a list of common extensions to avoid using the parent ..it ended up like this.

```
cache_peer 127.0.0.1 parent 8080 0 no-query name=gobox
acl nopasa url_regex "/etc/squid3/nopasa.acl"
always_direct allow nopasa
never_direct deny nopasa
```

where the nopasa.acl is a list of common binary extensions such as swf, jpg, png, etc etc